What is the approach to read decimal data accurately for loading into SQL Server table?
I am using an Excel data source task and dumping this data into a SQL Server table using the oledb destination task.
When I do the configuration, SSIS automatically created the SQL Server table. The column with decimal values get created as FLOAT data type.
I am being told by colleague that the float data type in SQL Server is an approximation and this can cause wrong values when using this value for further calculations. Therefore I am told to make the SQL Server table column data type to be decimal(16, 2).
Now what must I do in SSIS for it to read the data as decimal(16, 2) rather than double precision float, so that it can load accurately into the SQL Server table?

I tried modifying the data type in the input columns section of the Excel data source task's advanced editor to DT_DECIMAL, but whenever I preview the data, this setting gets reset to its original type - double precision float. Is this expected that this setting gets overwritten?

Should I modify the external column data type of the Excel data source task's advanced editor to DT_DECIMAL?

Sould I add a data conversion task to do this conversion? But is this too late as the data is already read prior to reaching this task?


What is correct way to read the data accurately?

You say you're using "OLE-DB" - but are you using the current "OLE DB Driver 19" library, or are you using the ooooold stock MSSQL OLE-DB driver ("Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" aka "SQLOLEDB") that ships with Windows?

How is this relevant to the question. Primarily what is important is how excel data is read. Isn't it?

I asked to understand your context. But anyway, part of your problem is that DT_DECIMAL is not the right type for T-SQL's decimal(p,s) - use DT_NUMERIC instead because DT_DECIMAL is not parameterized for precision and scale but DT_NUMERIC is. See here.

Despite whatever you configured, the only number format in Excel is double. If Excel is used as an intermediate storage, you can't avoid effects related to conversion of numeric data to or from double precision format.
You should completely redesign your solution if you need to process numeric data with fixed precision.

Excel is not an intermediate storage. Although I don't remember an exact example, values in excel like 21.0 get read as 20.99999999 in SSIS. I'm trying to understand what I can do to fetch the exact value from excel.


You wrote "Excel data source task and dumping this data into a SQL Server". It means Excel is in the middle. 2. If 21.0 is received in DBMS as 20.99999999 it means this number is the result of mathematical operations. Excel always round numbers to display. There is no error or wrong operation here.


Integer numbers are represented in a floating-point format as is if they do not exceed the max of the mantissa. Integer 21 stored in an integer, decimal or any floating-point format comes to Excel will not be represented as 20.99999999 in any case.

I'd use a data conversion step in the SSIS package to convert the data post-Excel extract, which frees you from Excel's nuances.
Sometimes (actually quite often), Excel tries to be helpful in the way it converts data for on-screen presentation - but it's actually corrupting from a data purists' perspective.

Data conversion step would be after the excel source task. The point of this question is to ask how to read the excel value correctly.
